# MapDB maps creation in parallel

Tags: java, mapdb

I'm creating parallel Maps using MapDB - would like to know whether it's safe and can it be done in better way. also assume that each sales table query can result into million records.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        DB db = DBMaker.newFileDB("mapdbFile").transactionDisable().mmapFileEnablePartial().make();
        getEmployees().parallelStream().forEach(e -> createRecords(e, db));
    }

private static List<Employee> getEmployees(){
    /* return employees list */
}

private static void createRecords(Employee employee, DB db) {
    JdbcTemplate template = /* spring JdbcTemplate creation */
    String query = "select name from sales where emp_id = "+employee.getId();        
    final BTreeMap<String, Long> map = db.createTreeMap("Employee" + employee.getId())
            .nodeSize(32).comparator(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).make();
    template.query(query, rs -> {
        put(map, rs.getString("product_name"), rs.getLong("sales"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DB object is synchronized and is thread safe. So yes, parallel map creation is safe.

Comment: Will it be faster than creating maps in serial?